# Shared storage on mobile devices

Tags: java, codenameone

I am creating a music download app using codename one and java.i am trying to save the downloaded files in a location that can be accessed by other apps on the device. Basically, my questions are:

1. What is the best approach for this objective?
2. Where do I save the files so that the files can be accessed by other applications like the music player app?
3. Are there any tutorials or demos that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no such directory on iOS due to sandboxing. Also due the different approaches required on different platforms you are better off asking multiple questions rather than a single question for 3 platforms since it isn't possible to have a single answer that addresses all 3 platforms.

Comment: You can save music files into Music directory so that music player can easily sync all those. Use this url: String mSavePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);

Comment: @Paulw11 his question is pertaining Codename One, which is a cross-platform mobile development tool. I've edited his question to remove other tags.

Answer (score 1):

In Android its called ContentProvider (Ex. Contacts App provides its contacts)

I think this will be helpful for iOS :

You can share data of your app using NSDefault : 
Apple's documentation of that approach is (find  "Sharing Data with Your Containing App")

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

or use this http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions
http://www.enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Comment: Since this functionality is so different between Android & iOS we don't have a common abstraction for those in Codename One. You can use native interfaces to provide similar functionality for these features.